# Python debugger pdb.set_trace() raises segmentation fault

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdb

I am working on my company server with an ssh connection. I want to run some code with python debugger but it raises a segmentation fault exception. I am using ssh from Macbook terminal.

It's just the sentence 'Segmentation fault' without any clue.

```
$ python3 mycode.py
Segmentation fault
```

mycode.py:

```
import pdb

pdb.set_trace()

print('HELLO')
```

My colleagues don't have this issue.

If I remove the line `pdb.set_trace()`, it works perfectly.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the exact output of a terminal session where you execute this code?

Comment: You need to provide more details.
Are you using ssh with vs code, what are the details of server, have you got a screenshot of the error with details.

Comment: So you type `python3 mycode.py` and then there is nothing except `Segmentation fault`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 exactly

Comment: And if you remove the line `pdb.set_trace()`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an error in the version of packages that I have installed. Created an environment from scratch solved the issue.